# How to set a flag to records based on a keyword in sql

Tags: sql, hive, flags

I have a use case in which i want to flag a record based on a keyword followed by setting the same flag to the next set of records until we get another keyword.

For Example

```
I have two keyword ABC and XYZ

Action    Flag
ABC        Y
CDS        Y
DES        Y
EXD        Y
DEA        Y
XYZ        N
SED        N
DRF        N
WSA        N
ABC        Y and so on
```

So when i found ABC, it should set the flag Y followed the setting the flag Y to the next set of records until i find XYZ which then set the flag to N until i found ABC and so on.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you manipulate data outside of the DB and update/insert result? or you want it in pure SQL ?

Comment: @Alexei Data is already present in my warehouse. I have a transformed layer where in i need to put in this data by applying above transformation. So. basically it should be pure SQL. Is this doable?

Comment: @Ankug . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You seem to be assuming an ordering to the data.  This implies that some column contains the ordering information.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hacky but this should work:

Create test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(Ref  VARCHAR(3),
 Flag VARCHAR(1) NULL
);
INSERT INTO #TEST(Ref)
VALUES('ABC'), ('CDS'), ('DES'), ('EXD'), ('DEA'), ('XYZ'), ('SED'), ('DRF'), ('WSA'), ('ABC');
```

Update Records

```
DECLARE @Flag VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE @Ref VARCHAR(3);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT Ref
    FROM #TEST;
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Ref;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @Ref = 'ABC'
            BEGIN
                SET @Flag = 'Y';
        END;
        IF @Ref = 'XYZ'
            BEGIN
                SET @Flag = 'N';
        END;

        UPDATE #TEST
          SET
              Flag = @Flag
        WHERE Ref = @Ref;
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Ref;
    END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Select and drop test table

```
SELECT * FROM #TEST;
    DROP TABLE #TEST;
```

This returns:

```
Ref Flag
ABC Y
CDS Y
DES Y
EXD Y
DEA Y
XYZ N
SED N
DRF N
WSA N
ABC Y
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It worked. Can we do the same in hive as we don't have cursors in hive?

Comment: No worries, You'll be able to use the same logic but in a loop rather than a cursor

Answer (score 0):

If I can assume that there every ABC is followed by XYZ -- and never an ABC -- then you can define the groups by using cumulative sums of ABC and XYZ:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when action = 'ABC' then 1
                           when action = 'XYZ' then -1
                      end) over (order by ?) > 0
             then 'Y'
             else 'N'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

If the condition is not true, but these are just switches, then you need to look at the most recent value.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*,
       (case when max(case when action = 'ABC' then ? end) over (order by ?) >
                  max(case when action = 'XYZ' then ? end) over (order by ?)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Once again, `?` is the column that specifies the ordering.